# Azure cloud page blob stream

Tags: c#

A custom stream that is used to perform read and write operations directly into the page cloud blob

```
public sealed class WindowsAzureCloudPageBlobStream : Stream
{
    // 4 MB is the top most limit for page blob write operations
    public const int MaxPageWriteCapacity = 4 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Every operation on a page blob has to manipulate a value which is rounded up to 512 bytes
    private const int PageBlobPageAdjustmentSize = 512;

    private CloudPageBlob _pageBlob;
    private long _streamLength;

    public WindowsAzureCloudPageBlobStream(CloudPageBlob pageBlob) : this(pageBlob, PageBlobPageAdjustmentSize)
    {
    }

    public WindowsAzureCloudPageBlobStream(CloudPageBlob pageBlob, long initialCapacity)
    {
        _pageBlob = pageBlob;
        Position = 0;

        if (_pageBlob.Exists())
        {
            _streamLength = GetCurrentCapacity();
        }
        else
        {
            _pageBlob.Create(RoundUpToPageBlobSize(initialCapacity));
            _streamLength = 0;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get
        {
            return _pageBlob != null;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get
        {
            return _pageBlob != null;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get
        {
            return _pageBlob != null;
        }
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get
        {
            return _streamLength;
        }
    }

    public override long Position { get; set; }

    public override void Flush() { /*No need to flush*/ }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        switch (origin)
        {
            case SeekOrigin.Begin:
                if (offset > Length)
                {
                    var errorMessage = SafeFormatter.Format(CloudLocalization.Culture, CloudLocalization.OffsetOutOfRange, Length, offset);
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessage);
                }

                Position = offset;
                break;

            case SeekOrigin.Current:
                if (Position + offset > Length)
                {
                    var errorMessage = SafeFormatter.Format(CloudLocalization.Culture, CloudLocalization.OffsetOutOfRange, Length, Position + offset);
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessage);
                }

                Position += offset;
                break;

            case SeekOrigin.End:
                if (Length + offset > Length)
                {
                    var errorMessage = SafeFormatter.Format(CloudLocalization.Culture, CloudLocalization.OffsetOutOfRange, Length, Length + offset);
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessage);
                }

                Position = Length + offset;
                break;

            default: throw new InvalidOperationException(SafeFormatter.Format(CloudLocalization.Culture, CloudLocalization.SeekOperationNotSupported, origin));
        }

        return Position;
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        var newLength = RoundUpToPageBlobSize(value);
        if (newLength == Length) { return; }

        var capacity = GetCurrentCapacity();
        if (newLength > capacity) { Resize(newLength); }

        _streamLength = newLength;
        if (Position > newLength) { Position = newLength; }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        using (var readStream = _pageBlob.OpenRead())
        {
            readStream.Seek(Position, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var readCount = readStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
            Position += readCount;

            return readCount;
        }
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var additionalOffset = 0;
        var bytesToWriteTotal = count;

        while (bytesToWriteTotal > 0)
        {
            var bytesToWriteTotalAdjusted = RoundUpToPageBlobSize(bytesToWriteTotal);

            // If we do not have enough space in the cloud, we'll reserve more
            var capacity = GetCurrentCapacity();
            var delta = Position + bytesToWriteTotalAdjusted - capacity;
            if (delta > 0) { Resize(capacity + delta); }

            // Azure does not allow us to write as many bytes as we want
            // Max allowed size per write is 4MB
            var bytesToWriteNow = Math.Min((int)bytesToWriteTotalAdjusted, MaxPageWriteCapacity);
            var adjustmentBuffer = new byte[bytesToWriteNow];

            // In case we need to write a number of bytes that cannot be splitted into 512-byte blocks
            // We need to adjust the buffer:
            // 1. Read from current offset a chunk that can be splitted into 512-byte blocks
            // 2. Merge new data with read data
            // 3. Write the modified data back
            if (bytesToWriteTotal < bytesToWriteTotalAdjusted && bytesToWriteTotal < MaxPageWriteCapacity)
            {
                var currentPosition = Position;
                var bytesRead = Read(adjustmentBuffer, 0, adjustmentBuffer.Length);

                // If we fail to read the required amount of bytes, it means that our stream is not valid
                if (bytesRead != adjustmentBuffer.Length)
                {
                    var errorMessage = SafeFormatter.Format(CloudLocalization.Culture, CloudLocalization.ReadWriteMissmatch, bytesRead, adjustmentBuffer.Length);
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessage);
                }

                Position = currentPosition;
                Array.Copy(buffer, offset + additionalOffset, adjustmentBuffer, 0, bytesToWriteTotal);
            }
            else
            {
                Array.Copy(buffer, offset + additionalOffset, adjustmentBuffer, 0, bytesToWriteNow);
            }

            // We cannot write in the middle of the page, need to adjust our position:
            // 1. Set position to the closest full block offset
            // 2. Read additional data from stream
            // 3. Adjust current buffer to include read data
            var positionSetToStartOfPage = (Position / PageBlobPageAdjustmentSize) * PageBlobPageAdjustmentSize;
            var steps = Position - positionSetToStartOfPage;
            if (steps != 0)
            {
                Position = positionSetToStartOfPage;
                var positionCorrectionBuffer = new byte[steps];

                // If we fail to read the required amount of bytes, it means that our stream is not valid
                var bytesRead = Read(positionCorrectionBuffer, 0, (int)steps);
                if (bytesRead != steps)
                {
                    var errorMessage = SafeFormatter.Format(CloudLocalization.Culture, CloudLocalization.ReadWriteMissmatch, bytesRead, steps);
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessage);
                }

                Position = positionSetToStartOfPage;
                var tempBuffer = new byte[adjustmentBuffer.Length];

                Array.Copy(positionCorrectionBuffer, 0, tempBuffer, 0, positionCorrectionBuffer.Length);
                Array.Copy(adjustmentBuffer, 0, tempBuffer, positionCorrectionBuffer.Length, adjustmentBuffer.Length - steps);

                adjustmentBuffer = tempBuffer;
            }

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(adjustmentBuffer, 0, bytesToWriteNow, false, false))
            {
                _pageBlob.WritePages(memoryStream, Position);
            }

            // If we had to make adjustments to stream position, we failed to write some of the data from initial buffer
            // Mark that data as non-processed and try to write it during the next iteration
            if (steps != 0) { bytesToWriteNow -= (int)steps; }

            Position += bytesToWriteNow;
            additionalOffset += bytesToWriteNow;
            bytesToWriteTotal -= bytesToWriteNow;

            if (Position > Length) { _streamLength = Position; }
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Free the overused space
        var capacity = GetCurrentCapacity();
        if (Length < capacity) { Resize(Length); }

        _pageBlob = null;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private void Resize(long value)
    {
        var newCapacity = RoundUpToPageBlobSize(value);
        _pageBlob.Resize(newCapacity);

        if (Length > newCapacity) { _streamLength = newCapacity; }
        if (Position > newCapacity) { Position = newCapacity; }
    }

    private long GetCurrentCapacity()
    {
        _pageBlob.FetchAttributes();
        return _pageBlob.Properties.Length;
    }

    private static long RoundUpToPageBlobSize(long size) { 
       return (size + PageBlobPageAdjustmentSize - 1) & ~(PageBlobPageAdjustmentSize - 1); }
    }
}
```

How can I improve my algorithm? Do I have any weaknesses in the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of your constructors is called with an passed `pageBlob` which is `null` you get an `NullReferenceException` at the point of calling `if (_pageBlob.Exists())` which is bad. You should throw an `ArgumentNullException`at the start of that method if `pageBlob` is `null`.

Based on that I can't see how the `CanXXX` properties should return `false`. If the object (`WindowsAzureCloudPageBlobStream`) is disposed these properties should throw an [`ObjectDisposedException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.objectdisposedexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

#### public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)

You don't check if the given `offset` is negativ. Assume the passed in `origin == SeekOrigin.Begin` and the `offset == -1` now `Position == -1` which will in the `Read()` method by seeking to `Position` result in an `IOException` because that makes an attempt to place the `Position` before the beginning of the stream.